# I need to convert list of lists into a table to be send within email in python

Tags: python

I need to convert list of lists into a table to be send within an email in python. Basically, I am building body of the email that would include data formatted as a table and then send as an email. I would use non-HTML email. What is the best way to go about it. For simplicity, here is my list of lists:

```py
L = [
    ['mazda', 'red', 'four door', 'sedan'],
    ['toyota', 'black', 'four door', 'sedan'],
    ['honda', 'blue', 'five door', 'suv']
]
```

And email would look something like:

Thanks for looking into the cars below:

```
---------------------------------------
| Model | Color | Door Config | Type  |
---------------------------------------
| Mazda | red   | four door   | sedan |
```

Comment: If you are using a non-HTML email, what type of table would you want exactly?

Comment: added table format above.

Comment: What about https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/ ?

Comment: I see that might actually work. Thanks I will check it out

Comment: `print(tabulate(table, headers='firstrow', tablefmt='grid'))`. You'd need to install tabulate for that.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**

```
def generate_table_str(data, header):
    data_max_len = max(len(i) for j in data for i in j)
    header_max_len = max(len(i) for i in header)
    max_len = max(data_max_len, header_max_len)

    table_header = '| '
    table_header += ' | '.join( (f"{word:{max_len}}" for word in header))
    table_header += '|'

    devider_str = '-' * len(table_header)

    header_str = f'{devider_str}\n{table_header}\n{devider_str}\n'
    table_str = header_str

    for inner in data:
        table_row_str = '| '
        table_row_str += ' | '.join( (f"{word:{max_len}}" for word in inner))
        table_row_str += '|'
        
        table_str += f'{table_row_str}\n'

    table_str += f'{devider_str}'

    return table_str

data = [
    ['mazda', 'red', 'four door', 'sedan'],
    ['toyota', 'black', 'four door', 'sedan'],
    ['honda', 'blue', 'five door', 'suv']
]
header = ['Model', 'Color', 'Door Config', 'Type']
table_str = generate_table_str(data, header)

print(f'{table_str}')
```

**Output:**

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| Model       | Color       | Door Config | Type       |
--------------------------------------------------------
| mazda       | red         | four door   | sedan      |
| toyota      | black       | four door   | sedan      |
| honda       | blue        | five door   | suv        |
--------------------------------------------------------
```